# Código no Arduino: Aplicação via Bluetooth

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

A imagem abaixo mostra o aplicativo que criei para tentar me comunicar com o arduino. Cada opção envia via serial uma letra como mostra na tela. A questão é que eu preciso garantir que o usuário siga uma ordem: escolher tema, finalizar escolha e controlar o audio gerado. Mas estou com sérias duvidas em relação a como codar isso e também como funcionaria o envio serial. Segue a imagem do aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue o código que tentei gerar, mas o mesmo mal funciona(apenas executa o setup):

```
#include <SD.h>                      // need to include the SD library
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 53  //example uses hardware SS pin 53 on Mega2560
#include <TMRpcm.h>           //  also need to include this library...
TMRpcm tmrpcm;   // create an object for use in this sketch
char tema,escolha,controle;

void setup(){
  tmrpcm.speakerPin = 11; //11 on Mega, 9 on Uno, Nano, etc
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
    Serial.println("SD fail");  
    return;   // don't do anything more if not
  }
  tmrpcm.play("start.wav"); //the sound file "music" will play each time the arduino powers up, or is reset
}

void loop(){ 
  if(Serial.available()){
    while(1){
      tema = Serial.read();
      if(tema == 'a' || tema == 'b' || tema =='c'){
        break;   
      }
    }
    while(1){
      escolha = Serial.read();
      if(escolha == 'd'){
        break;
      }
    }
    if(tema == 'a'){
      tmrpcm.play("bolsa.wav");
    }
    else if(tema == 'b'){
      tmrpcm.play("tec.wav");
    }
    else if(tema == 'c'){
      tmrpcm.play("all.wav");
    }
    while(1){
      controle = Serial.read();
      if(controle =='e' || controle =='E'){
        tmrpcm.pause();
      }
      else if(controle =='f'){
        tmrpcm.stopPlayback();
      }
      if(tmrpcm.isPlaying() == 0){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Desculpe se estou cometendo alguns erros grosseiros, mas é minha primeira tentativa de application com o arduino. O mesmo está pegando os audios de um sd card. Segue abaixo o código de bloco do aplicativo. 
Em resumo minha maior duvida está em como funcionaria a comunicação serial: se eu checko uma das opções por exemplo, ela enviara "a" sempre e portanto ao apertar finalizar escolhas eu estaria enviando "a" e "d"? Dúvidas como essa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]